# Error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, permisos

Tengo un controlador de tipo "invokable" el cuál utilizo sólamente para poder asignarle a un rol, alguna de las habilidades disponibles. No puedo asignarle una habilidad y me gustaría poder hacerlo mediante el front-end.

En total tengo 4 tablas que se relacionan unas con las otras, pero la importante para mí en este momento es `ability_role` ya que en esta es en donde un rol es asociado con una habilidad en particular.

1. Roles
2. Roles_user
3. Abilities
4. Ability_role

Lo que quiero hacer es poder asignarle a 1 rol una hablilidad de las que muestre en el front-end y mediante un botón llevar a cabo esta solicitud, pero obtengo un error que es el siguiente:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

Lo que me parece algo extraño ya que tanto en mis rutas web (**web/routes.php**) y en mi formulario especifíco que el método sea de POST.

En mi modelo de Role tengo el siguiente método en donde obtengo una relación con la tabla de las habilidades, esto me ha funcionado anteriormente usando PHP Tinker pero aún no con el front-end:

```
    public function allowTo($ability)
    {
        $this->abilities()->sync($ability, false);
    }
```

En un select estoy mostrándo todas las habilidades que tengo en mi tabla de **abilities** y en el elemento de `<option value="">` estoy pasándole el ID de las habilidades.

```
<form 
    action="assignAbility"
    method="POST"
>   @csrf

    <select 
        name="abilities[]"
        id="abilities"
        multiple
    >
        @foreach ($abilities as $ability)
            <option value="{{ $ability->id }}">
                {{ $ability->name }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <button 
        type="submit">
        Asignar
    </button>
</form>
```

Mi ruta web es la siguiente:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->prefix('admin')->group(function (){
    Route::post('/assignAbility', AbilitiesRoleController::class)->name('assignAbility');
});
```

En el controlador **AbilitiesRolesController** proceso la solicitud del formulario y espero poder asignarle una habilidad a un rol.

```
    public function __invoke(Request $request, Role $role, Ability $abilities)
    {   
        $abilities = Ability::find($abilities);
        
        $abilities->each(fn ($ability) => $role->allowTo($ability));
        
        return redirect()->route('assignAbility');
    }
```

Al seleccionar una opción del select, se debería de tomar el ID de una habilidad y mediante la relación que el servidor pueda hacer la asignación de una habilidad para con un rol.

Por el momento no he podido llevar a cabo esta solicitud en su totalidad ya que lo que obtengo es este mensaje:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

https://flareapp.io/share/OmVy1Bp5

Estoy algo confundido ya que en ningún lugar estoy usando el verbo GET lo cuál me parece algo extraño, y en realidad desconozco si en algún lugar hago una "malinterpretación" para con el servidor, lo que deseo es poder escribir en la tabla de **ability_role** y mediante el método de `allowTo` poder asociar una habilidad para con un rol. Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Es una proyecto Laravel version 8, gracias!

Comment: Gracias, aún corrigiendo esta parte sigo obteniéndo el mismo error.

Comment: Checa esa parte ya que se me había olvidado que esa ruta forma parte de un middleware, y sí tengo más rutas en cuanto a habilidades, ¿debería de mostrar esas tambien? Ya que bueno, esas rutas no forman parte del controlador invokable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el error y se encontraba en esta línea:

```
return redirect()->route('assignAbility');
```

Estaba tratando de redireccionar usando la misma ruta que tenía para el método de POST en el formulario, esta línea intentaba realizar una solicitud GET, uno no puede tener 1 mismo nombre para una solicitud GET y POST. Cambié a esto y ya no tuve ese error:

```
return redirect()->back();
```